# Flask API in Python: POST a hosted PDF's URL for the server to download

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, pythonanywhere

I am using PythonAnywhere to try and run a flask API that allows the user to POST a link to an online .PDF file with the goal of downloading the file to the flask's working directory.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import requests
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure the logger file
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a file handler
handler = logging.FileHandler('log.txt')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a logging format
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(handler)

@app.route('/download', methods=['POST'])
def download_file():
    # Log that the function has been called
    logger.info("download_file function called")

    # Get the URL of the hosted PDF file
    pdf_url = request.values.get('url')

    # Log that the function has been called
    logger.info("URL has been retrieved called")

    # Download the PDF file
    response = requests.get(pdf_url)
    file = response.content

    # Log that the function has been called
    logger.info("PDF file downloaded")

    # Save the PDF file to the working directory of the API
    with open('downloaded_file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(file)

    # Log that the function has been called
    logger.info("PDF file saved to working directory")

    # Log that the operation was successful overall
    return 'File downloaded and saved successfully!'
```

I am testing in Postman like this:

```
POST http://[myurl].pythonanywhere.com/download

KEY: url
VALUE: "https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15.pdf"
```

The download is only successful when I hardcode the URL before defining the functions, but when I instead try to POST the URL to the API, it does not work properly and receive "400 Bad Request" as an error. It seems likely to be due to passing of the symbols in the URL, but I am unsure.

Comment: Verify that `hello_world()` works with POST. I imagine the identical symptom could be reproduced with a shorter URL, such as `https://www2.gov.bc.ca/assets/`. It would be helpful to also reproduce with `curl`.  I suspect the `:` colon is not being escaped to `%3a`. Examine the details of how client, and server, are treating form data encoding.

Comment: Show us detailed logging, please. That is, please have `download_file` log something immediately upon entering, and then after the pdf_url assignment, and after the .get() call. We need to see how far it got, or if the web framework even called it at all. What server software is sending requests along to Flask, here?

Comment: If you're using a free account, your code has only access to whitelisted domains on PA.

Comment: @J_H Thank you very much for taking the time to write back. 

Regarding your first comment: I fixed hello_world() to work with both GET and POST by writing it like this:

`
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # handle POST request
        return 'Hello from Flask!'
    else:
        # handle GET request
        return 'Hello from Flask!'
`

I implemented detailed logging, but all I am receiving is the text "2022-12-24 19:33:44,944 - pdfs2_flask_app - INFO - download_file function called".

Comment: Let's say that `pdf_url` is hard coded, so we needn't worry about whether it has the intended value or not. Now let's go break a "known working" function, hello_world(). Suppose that before the return it starts with this call: `requests.get(pdf_url)`. I haven't seen any logged evidence yet that that call would succeed. I predict that adding it would break the function, due to a firewall prohibiting your script from making the outbound .get()

Comment: My apologies for the erroneous edit to my comment above, I did not know the output would be like that and it is now past the 5 minute edit period. I will give that a shot next, J_H.

 I wanted to add quickly to address @caseneuve to mention I am using a paid account on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: @J_H YOu were right. 1st, I changed the PDF to an IRS document as it's a shorter link. 2nd, when I hardcode this to pdf_url, it works in both hello_world() and in download_file(). I updated the code in my post above.

This suggests the issue is related to the passing of url symbols (colon, etc). I will work to troubleshoot this, but would be keen to know if you have any suggestions. Thank you so much for your time, it means a lot!

Comment: Avoid ad hoc encoding. Do yourself a favor. Write some [unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) that demonstrate [urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) and related functions, using familiar URLs that you care about. Notice that encoding within form body is a bit different from the `/foo?q=kw&page=2` encoding you commonly see with GET requests. Then go back to your POST method, log everything in sight, and _carefully_ decode those args so you're logging a correctly spelled URL & can successfully download it.

Comment: Thank you, @J_H. I was able to get the code fixed and I put the revised code in the post. I did not need to do any encoding to the URL, actually. The two things that were required: 1) Changing the retrieval of the URL to the hosted PDF file to this: pdf_url = request.values.get('url')  and 2) removing the quotation marks from the URL in the Postman VALUE. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out on this!